# How to find memory used each switch case

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have a switch that include many case to like this example that get many data from database.

```
switch(number)
{
   case: "1"
   {
       getdata1();
   }
   case: "2"
   {
       getdata2();
   }
   case: "3"
   {
       getdata3();
   }
}
```

now,i want find memory used each case and show to user.

thanks.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: i want show memory used this case to user after run each case.
For example : Show memory used for case 1 123421 byte and Memory used for case 2 24424245232 byte.

Comment: "memory used" just isn't a clear concept here - do you want to report on how much new memory is allocated by the functions that each branch calls? Are you wanting to include or ignore memory allocated if e.g. the functions have to be newly JITted?

Comment: Thanks @damien-the-unbeliever.
My Web Applicatin after run this Method get **error Exception Of Type system.outOfMemoryException was thrown**.now i want that Which case cause this error.i think that should get Which one case more used memory and approved this case.

Comment: If only `OutOfMemoryException` were only thrown when you're genuinely out of memory (address space). Unfortunately, that's not the case. There are numerous places in the framework where this exception might be thrown and they have nothing to do with memory usage.